# My step counter does not reset the steps, even after uninstall

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I use Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER I know it only resets when rebooting. Is there an alternative way to reset the steps to 0 when pressing a button?

Please see my code, you will find the Runactivity.class

Maybe I can do it in another way which resets the steps.
without having me to reboot every time.

```
public class RunActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private TextView count;
    boolean activityRunning;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_run);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String naam   = bundle.getString("naam");
        TextView NaamView = null;

        Button stopRun = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopRun);

        count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countView);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        NaamView =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.naamRunText);

        NaamView.setText(naam);

        stopRun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String countValue = count.getText().toString();



                Log.d("countVAL", String.valueOf(countValue));


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(RunActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


                bundle.putString("naam", naam);
                sensorManager.flush(RunActivity.this);
                sensorManager.unregisterListener(RunActivity.this);
                count.setText("0");
                onStop();

                myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(myIntent);


            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activityRunning = true;
        Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if(countSensor != null){
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Jouw apparaat heeft geen sensor!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(activityRunning){
            count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        }else{
            event.values[0] = 0;
        }



    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        activityRunning = false;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Comment: And your code, please....

Comment: @Gavriel I did edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched on it and tried to do it with different ways. Nothing Helped.
Then I found the most simple way possible.

In `onSensorChanged()` just add the counter so when ever `onSensorChanged()` will be called (it will be called on every step), counter will simply count the steps then show this counter to your UI instead of showing the value of `event.values[0]`

on your Reset button make the counter 0 again.

Answer (score 3):

When you click the reset button in the app save the current step count to SharedPreferences. And you'll need a way to find out when was the last reboot because every time you reboot the saved count number gets invalid.

```
private Integer stepsInSensor;
private Integer stepsAtReset;

void onCreate() {
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
  stepsAtReset = prefs.getInt("stepsAtReset", 0);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    stepsAtReset = stepsInSensor;
    if (stepsAtReset != null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =
            getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("stepsAtReset", stepsAtReset);
        editor.commit();
    }
    // you can now display 0:
    count.setText(String.valueOf(0));
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(activityRunning){
        stepsInSensor = Integer.valueOf(event.values[0]);
        if (stepsAtReset = null) {
            stepsAtReset = stepsInSensor;
        }
        int stepsSinceReset = stepsInSensor - stepsAtReset;
        if (stepsSinceReset < 0) {
            stepsAtReset = stepsInSensor;
            stepsSinceReset = 0;
        }
        count.setText(String.valueOf(stepsSinceReset));
    }else{
        event.values[0] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example? After I hit stop I want the value to be zero.

Comment: I did exactly like you said, the sep counter is still the same after I hit the stop button.

Comment: I added a line to display "0" in onClick. But did you try to do some steps after clicking the reset?

Comment: Hi That line did not work, when I start a "run" again I see the full steps if I do more steps it goes higher and when I hit stop en hit "Run again" I see the highest one. so basically nothing changed by using this code. I rebooted my phone and reinstalled the app.

Comment: We don't know about any "run", "run again" buttons. If you have code that you haven't post, then obviously you'll need to understand the answer and adopt it to your secret part of the code.

Comment: The "RUN" I am telling is just a button that goes to Runactivity that is the code I shared.

Comment: I changed MY_PREFS_NAME to just "" because it gave me an error.

Comment: @Gavriel how do i resume and count on after restarting the phone

Comment: @theoyuncu8 on starting the app you check the stored value in SharedPreferences. If there's something then you add that value to the count and remove the value from SharedPreferences.

Comment: @Gavriel When I reboot it starts counting as -(negative).  I bought the code exactly from you. Would you like to review it?

Comment: @theoyuncu8 I improved the code to deal with "negative" values. It'll display 0 in that case and will start to count from the 1st time it gets a sensor reading.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, based on the [Sensor API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

> A sensor of this type returns the number of steps taken by the user
>   since the last reboot while activated. The value is returned as a
>   float (with the fractional part set to zero) and **is reset to zero only
>   on a system reboot.**

It can only be reset when the system is rebooted